# Get data from multidimensional array js

Tags: javascript, arrays, get

I have a JS array, for example:

```
const array1 = [{"entrance":"20","a":"10"},{"entrance":"15","b":"25"}];
```

I want to get `entrance` values as a new array. Till today I'm using a `for-loop` to do it, like this:

```
var entrance = [];
for(i=0;i<array1.length;i++){
  entrance[i] = array1[i]["entrance"];
}
```

This works perfect, but I wonder if there is a prettier way to do this. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Use `.map()`:

```js
const array1 = [{"entrance":"20","a":"10"},{"entrance":"15","b":"25"}];
const entrance = array1.map((e) => e.entrance);

console.log(entrance);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

> The [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

```js
const array1 = [{"entrance":"20","a":"10"},{"entrance":"15","b":"25"}];

var entrance = array1.map(i => i.entrance);
console.log(entrance);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty way using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```
const array1 = [{"entrance":"20","a":"10"},{"entrance":"15","b":"25"}];
const entrances = array1.map(({ entrance }) => entrance);
```

Answer (score 0):

It has not been mentioned yet. You could use `forEach`:

```
const array1 = [{"entrance":"20","a":"10"},{"entrance":"15","b":"25"}];
const res = [];
array1.forEach((obj) => {res.push(obj.entrance)});
console.log(res);
```